# Setting background drawable to a TextView is not working

Tags: android, background, textview, drawable

I've looked it up everywhere on StackOverflow and can't seem to find an answer to my question. I am running an API v.16 device, and the background-updating method for a TextView which uses Drawable as its background, is provided below. Everything else works--the TextViews change their textSize and height/width successfully, in the unmentioned here part of the total code. Any ideas on what might be the problem? The app doesn't stop, there is just no change in the thickness of the stroke. In fact, the TextView looses its background in the change altogether. It's original background is a corner-smoothed rectangle of a certain stroke width, which should halve in size, as well as its stroke width. After the change no background is getting displayed in the TextView altogether.

```
if (textViewsArrayList.size() != 0) textViews.get(textViewsArrayList.size() - 1).post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            for (counter = 0; counter < textViewsArrayList.size(); counter++) {

                textViewsArrayList.get(counter).getLayoutParams().height = (int)               
                (textViewsArrayList.get(counter).getLayoutParams().height / 2);

                textViewsArrayList.get(counter).getLayoutParams().width = (int) (textViewsArrayList.get(counter).getLayoutParams().width / 2);
                ((TextView) textViewsArrayList.get(counter)).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, (int) (((TextView) textViewsArrayList.get(counter)).getTextSize() / 2));

                GradientDrawable background = (GradientDrawable) textViewsArrayList.get(counter).getBackground();

                background.setStroke((int) (4 / displayMetrics.density / 2), (int) Color.parseColor("#FFA500"));;

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

                    ((TextView) textViewsArrayList.get(counter)).setBackground((Drawable) background);

                } else {

                    ((TextView) textViewsArrayList.get(counter)).setBackgroundDrawable((Drawable) background);

                }

            }

        }

});
```

While the xml for the TextView in question is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:tag="layout">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_xml"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:tag="textview_in question"/>

etc.
```

As for the drawable xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="#FF6600" />

    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

</shape>
```

Comment: remove         android:background="@drawable/drawable_xml"
from your xml. Only set the background from java code

Comment: hey, your code is perfect when I checked your code and I have answered your question as well.

Comment: @ Anjali: tried it, but it didn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Could this perhaps be an issue with when the drawables of views get drawn? Anyone has expertise on that?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

> **Setting background drawable to a TextView dynamically:**

```
TextView txtHello = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
txtHello.setLayoutParams(lparams);
txtHello.setText("Hello World");
txtHello.setTextSize(14);
txtHello.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9C9C9C"));
txtHello.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.ic_launcher, null, null, null);
```

> **Setting background drawable to a TextView using xml:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="68dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

put the below xml file into your drawable folder:

**rounded_corner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="#FF6600" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I want is set it dynamically, because it is for adjusting layout for different devices, and I just can't see it happening that I may entry a value for every single thing in the app, it would be disastrous.

Comment: Hey, I have updated the code, please look into it, I have done it into my project and it is working fine, so please check it.

Comment: @ Parth: Thanks, your response helped me solve the problem. It hinted me that there may be a problem with my view bounds. Indeed, my textview had match_parent instead of a fixed value for its layout_width. I guess this was somehow causing the problem, possibly to do with the timing of system requesting the parent's size of the listview item (match_parent) for processing the change in background drawable. The fact that I change the parent size (listview item's size) may have been the problem, because that could have been happening before the system could finalize the new value.

Comment: If this will be helpful to you, please upvote my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but upvoting an answer meaning that it's correct, yours only accidentally helped me find the right answer, it does not actually contain the right answer.